# Transaction Rollback is not heppening when error occour in nested method

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, transactional

In my recent project I faced a scenario where I need to rollback database operation when error happen in nested method. Earlier I worked with `@Transactional` on single method. That time it worked fine. But in current scenario I have dependency on another method. So I need to rollback when error happen is nested method. I want to rollback in this method

```
@Transactional
@Override
public String updateCustomOfficeHour(OfficeHour officeHour) {
    if (officeHour.getId() == null || officeHourRepository.getFirstById(officeHour.getId()) == null)
        throw new EntityNotFoundException("No Office-Hour found with this id");

    OfficeHour temp = officeHourRepository.getFirstById(officeHour.getId());
    List<OfficeHour> officeHours = officeHourRepository.findByFromDateAndToDate(temp.getFromDate(), temp.getToDate());

    List<OfficeHour> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (OfficeHour officeHourObj : officeHours) {
        officeHourObj.setDeleted(true);
        tempList.add(officeHourObj);
    }
    officeHourRepository.saveAll(tempList);
    this.createCustomOfficeHour(officeHour);
    return "Updated Custom-Office-Hour";
}
```

Here I have a database operation in line `officeHourRepository.saveAll(tempList);`
I need to rollback when error occur in method `this.createCustomOfficeHour(officeHour);`. This method is

```
   @Transactional
    @Override
    public String createCustomOfficeHour(OfficeHour officeHour) {
        if (officeHour.getFromDate() == null || officeHour.getToDate() == null
                || officeHour.getFirstOutTime() == null || officeHour.getLastInTime() == null
                || officeHour.getInTime() == null || officeHour.getOutTime() == null)
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Null value received for OfficeHour fields!");

        if (officeHour.getToDate().compareTo(officeHour.getFromDate()) < 0)
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("FromDate is Getter than ToDate");

        if (officeHourRepository.isFromDateExist(officeHour.getFromDate()).longValue() > 0
                || officeHourRepository.isToDateExist(officeHour.getToDate()).longValue() > 0) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("FromDate/ToDate is already assigned");
        }

        if (officeHourRepository.isDateExistsBetweenFromAndToDate(officeHour.getFromDate(), officeHour.getToDate()).longValue() > 0)
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Office Hour Already Assigned In This Range");


        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
           ........
           ........
           ........
           officeHourRepository.save(obj);

        }
        return "Custom Office-Hour Created";
    }
```

And this is my `Exception` class

```
public class EntityNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    public EntityNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

I have also added `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect` in `application.properties`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `EntityNotFoundException`  is a non-checked exception and following the [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative):

> Spring default behavior for declarative transaction management follows
>   EJB convention (roll back is automatic only on unchecked exceptions)

the transaction should be rolled back by default.

This is because `updateCustomOfficeHour` and `createCustomOfficeHour` are processed under same transaction (there is no override of propagation here so the default REQUIRED is used).

You could add an explicit rollback for your exception on the `updateCustomOfficeHour` method but that should be redundant anyway:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = {EntityNotFoundException.class})
```

Comment: I added `@Transactional(rollbackFor = {EntityNotFoundException.class})` on the `updateCustomOfficeHour` But I get red alert for `rollbackFor`. It show `Cannot resolve method 'rollbackFor' `. What should I do now?

Comment: If you are using `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` there should be `rollbackFor` @AvijitBarua

Comment: @ShafinMahmud I got `rollBackOn` but that didn't work.

Comment: Try to set @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) on the inner method.

Comment: @MaciejKowalski I set `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)` on `createCustomOfficeHour` and set `@Transactional(rollbackFor = {EntityNotFoundException.class})` on `updateCustomOfficeHour`. But unfortunately got no expected result.